# Flutter two children: <Widget> inside same Stack()

Tags: flutter, gps

How can I fuse two children `<widget>` inside the same `Stack()`> For example, fuse this ...

```
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition:
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,
          currentLocation.longitude), zoom: 17),
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      mapType: _currentMapType,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),

    ),
    Padding(
```

with this:

```
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        // Replace this container with your Map widget
        Container(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Positioned(
```

Comment: you have already used two children under stack(), what you're trying to achieve? Do you want to place the GoogleMap() widget under the container for a background color?

Comment: Can you share UI ?

Answer (score 0):

What about the `...` operator which flattens a list into a list. E.g:

```
  List<Widget> getFirstStackChildren() {
    return [
      Text("first stack first child"),
      Text("first stack second child")
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> getSecondStackChildren() {
    return [
      Text("second stack first child"),
      Text("second stack second child")
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...getFirstStackChildren(),
            ...getSecondStackChildren(),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```